# Excel: Finding next equal match in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've googled for a solution to my problem for days and I just can't seem to get my head around how to do this.

I have 28 chickens and I track the eggs each one lays each month. My Excel sheet looks like this:

[Current Egg-cel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuzQW.png)

Column C is populated by the formula:

```
=LARGE($A$2:$A$29,$B1)
```

I'm using column B to increment the LARGE function

I want column D to populate with which chicken number laid the quantity in column C.

Obviously INDEX MATCH or VLOOKUP returns the first match for all equal values. How do I find the the next match? i.e.

[Egg-cell sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6TUu.png)

I've seen similar questions and solutions but I for the life of me can not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in D2:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$29)/($A$2:$A$29=C2),COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)))
```

And drag down

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Scott! I was completely unfamiliar with the aggregate function. You've made life easier for this small time chicken farmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to add a few *helper* columns, this is a simple way to go:

[image]

The formula in column C creates a *unique number* by bringing together the eggs laid and the chicken number

```
=--(A2&"."&B2)
```

Column D is just your `LARGE` formula,

```
=LARGE($C$2:$C$4,B2)
```

Column E just gets the integer part of column D

```
=INT(D2)
```

And finally Column F gets the decimal part (chicken number) from column D

```
=--REPLACE(MOD(D2,1),1,2,"")
```

Comment: Also a neat way to accomplish what I need. Thank you CallumDA. This may help me with another project I'm working on.